# 7z exclude top level few folders

Tags: compression, archive, 7zip

I would like to compress the folder having the following structure using 7zip or.. using any other zip archive utility available for windows that can use the command line argument in windows and achieve what I want to accomplish.. Here is my folder structure:

```
/images
/cache
/skin/common/images
/skin/skin1/images
/extensions/extension1/images
```

What I want to do is, I just want to exclude the top level "images" and "cache" folders from the root folder (The very first two entries in my listing above).
I have tried using the `xr!images` or `xr!/images` but.. `xr!images` removes all images folder. `xr!/images` just doesn't work.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general "how to use software" tech support.

Comment: Marc, This is part of my programming that I am trying to accomplish.. I am working on automated deployment script where I can't figure out how to exclude some of the folders while taking the backup of the original source before deploying the new code to the destination

Answer (score 0):

Use `-x!images` instead of `-xr!images`.